# Open a URL in browser as a post build step in Jenkins

Tags: batch-file, jenkins

I am planning to open a URL in browser as a post build step in Jenkins. I tried using Pipeline Jenkins and included the code below:

```
node {
    stage ("execute"){
        bat 'start www.google.com'
    }
}
```

I'm getting output as:

```
Started by user anonymous
[Pipeline] node
Running on master in C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\free
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (execute)
[Pipeline] bat
[free] Running batch script

C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\free>start www.google.com 
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
Finished: SUCCESS
```

But the URL specified is not getting opened in browser. When I run the same command `start www.google.com` in command prompt, it is opening the Google site in default browser. How to solve this?

Comment: Are you running a batch script from Jenkins?

Comment: Tried doing it. Batch file even has same command what I've given in Jenkins

Comment: I apologize for what I've just said. I mis-read your post.